# Return single row using case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I keep my purchase and issue in my transaction table with type 0 and 1.
Now I want to retrieve sum of purchase and issue in single row with two columns. My query:

```
SELECT   (CASE WHEN TransType = 0 THEN SUM(Amount) END) PurchaseAmt, 
         (CASE WHEN TransType = 1 THEN SUM(Amount) END) IssueAmt
FROM     TransMaster 
WHERE    TransType in (0,1) 
GROUP BY TransType
```

Above query return following rows

```
PurchaseAmt                IssueAmt
13600123.00                NULL
NULL                       12952262.00][1]
```

[image]

But my expectation is single row as following

```
PurchaseAmt                IssueAmt
13600123.00                12952262.00
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN transtype = 0 THEN amount else 0
           END) PurchaseAmt, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN transtype = 1 THEN amount else 0
           END) IssueAmt 
FROM   transmaster 
WHERE  transtype IN ( 0, 1 )
```

Comment: Adding a `else` part with `0` in the `case statement` will make the query more understandable. Also add some explanation to the answer. I think that is the reason for **downvote**.

Comment: Between i didn't downvote. Will add a upvote to nullify

Comment: correct answer as i expected.thank you.